# Publish data from WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to WSO2 DAS

Tags: rest, soap, wso2-das, wso2-esb

Can we publish data from WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to WSO2 DAS like ESB 4.9? Is there any way or workarounds for create an event sink in wso2 ESB 4.8.1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can publish data from WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to WSO2 DAS. In ESB 4.8.1 does not have an event sink, it has BAM profiler for that purpose.

You can easily create a soap or http receiver in WSO2 DAS and Send data from ESB to http/soap endpoint of DAS receiver.

Comment: Thanx @Tharik. Is it compulsory to have an BAM profiler for publish data from ESB to DAS

Comment: No even you can use a SEND mediator to send events to Http/Soap receiver of DAS/CEP but BAM profiler uses thrift protocol which is better in performance.

Comment: Is Message Tracer also suitable for this?